# Event for when animation is completed in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have a number of animations I'd like to run, one after another. How can I tell when one is done so that I know to start the next?

**Update** Sorry, I should have mentioned that these are skeletal animations that I'm doing.

Comment: I use [GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap) for animation and would use [TimelineLite](http://greensock.com/timelinelite) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

1: You can enclose your animations in `setTimeout()` functions:

```
setTimeout( function() { animation1; }, waitTime );
setTimeout( function() { animation2; }, waitTime + duration_of_animation1 );
setTimeout( function() { animation3; }, waitTime + duration_of_animation2 );
```

2: Look at https://github.com/mrdoob/frame.js which has not been released yet.

Comment: Do you know if that frame.js is related to the one here? https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js

Answer (score 0):

For animations try to use tween library, it solves much more than this:

https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that these are skeletal animations imported from a BVH file. I don't think tween.js could help here, could it?

Comment: Ah, no i think tween will not help

Comment: Thanks anyway. Cool library though. It looks like something I'll be able to use some other time.